# Gta Online Mode

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

How do I get the two hundread thousand dollars for Gta online mode? I have signed up to the website and have not been able to get the money as promised.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't getting the money offered to you by Rockstar, you would need to go through their customer support and they will be able to help you.